Dynamic label text being "overwritten"
I am encountering what i believe to be a bug in either pinescript or tradingview itself
I have a script where I am plotting multiple VWAPS
Those vwaps have labels on them that are dynamically displaying the % change price needs to move to hit them
The issue here is that the labels are like overwriting the previous text (picture attached)
The initial label is not being deleted. Even though i have the label delete logic.
The reason I believe this to be a bug is that it doesn't always happen! They sometimes work great.
Specifically if i disable/re-enable the labels, they work perfect until i change the timeframe.
I have tried so many "fixes" and nothing works.
Here is the MR code block: Yes, i have also tried label.settext and it still does the exact same behaviour.
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © traderview2

//@version=5
indicator("VWAP TESTING", overlay = true)

import PineCoders/ConditionalAverages/1 as pc

///------------------------------------------- START USER INPUTS  --------------------------------------------///

// Enable/Disable & length - VWAPs
eDV = "-------- Enable VWAPs --------"
rvOn1 = input.bool(true, "R-VWAP #1:", group = eDV, inline = "rv1")
tfI1 = input.timeframe("1D", "Period", group = eDV, inline = "rv1")
rvOn2 = input.bool(true, "R-VWAP #1:", group = eDV, inline = "rv1")
tfI2 = input.timeframe("1W", "Period", group = eDV, inline = "rv1")

// Main VWAP Settings
m_V = "-------- Main VWAP Settings --------"
rVsrc = input.source(hlc3, "Rolling VWAP Source", group = m_V)
drawVLabels = input.bool(true, "Show VWAP Labels?", group = m_V)
textSize = input.string(defval='Normal', title='Label Text Size', 
 options=['Tiny', 'Small', 'Normal', 'Large', 'Huge'], group = m_V) 

// 1st  Rolling VWAP Inputs
r_v1 = "Rolling VWAP #1"
stdevM1 = input.float(0, "Bands Multiplier", group = r_v1, minval = 0.0, step = 0.5)
rV1color = input.color(color.orange, "Color", group = r_v1)

// 2nd  Rolling VWAP Inputs
r_v2 = "Rolling VWAP #2"
stdevM2 = input.float(0, "Bands Multiplier", group = r_v1, minval = 0.0, step = 0.5)
rV2color = input.color(color.green, "Color", group = r_v1)



///------------------------------------------- START ROLLING VWAP CODE --------------------------------------------///

// Function to calculate Rolling VWAP and bands
RollingVWAP(src, vol, tf, stdevMult) =>
    float sumSrcVol = pc.totalForTimeWhen(src * vol, timeframe.in_seconds(tf) * 1000, true, 10)
    float sumVol = pc.totalForTimeWhen(vol, timeframe.in_seconds(tf) * 1000, true, 10)
    float stdSrcVol = pc.totalForTimeWhen(vol * math.pow(src, 2), timeframe.in_seconds(tf) * 1000, true, 10)
    float rVWAP = sumSrcVol / sumVol
    
    // Calculate bands
    float rV = stdSrcVol / sumVol - math.pow(rVWAP, 2)
    rV := math.max(0, rV)
    float stDev = math.sqrt(rV)
    float upperBand = rVWAP + (stDev * stdevMult)
    float lowerBand = rVWAP - (stDev * stdevMult)
    
    [rVWAP, upperBand, lowerBand]

// Calculate each Rolling VWAP with its respective inputs
[rVWAP1, uppB1, lowB1] = RollingVWAP(rVsrc, volume, tfI1, stdevM1)
[rVWAP2, uppB2, lowB2] = RollingVWAP(rVsrc, volume, tfI2, stdevM2)


///------------------------------------------- START ROLLING VWAP PLOTS --------------------------------------------///

// Plotting Rolling VWAP #1
plot(rvOn1 ? rVWAP1 : na, "rVWAP #1", rV1color, style = plot.style_stepline)
uR1 = plot(rvOn1 and stdevM1 != 0 ? uppB1 : na, "rVWAP #1 Upper Band", color.new(rV1color, 50))
lR1 = plot(rvOn1 and stdevM1 != 0 ? lowB1 : na, "rVWAP #1 Lower Band", color.new(rV1color, 50))
fill(uR1, lR1, color.new(rV1color, 95), "rVWAP #1 Bands Fill")

// Plotting Rolling VWAP #1
plot(rvOn2 ? rVWAP2 : na, "rVWAP #2", rV2color, style = plot.style_stepline)
uR2 = plot(rvOn2 and stdevM2 != 0 ? uppB1 : na, "rVWAP #2 Upper Band", color.new(rV2color, 50))
lR2 = plot(rvOn2 and stdevM2 != 0 ? lowB1 : na, "rVWAP #2 Lower Band", color.new(rV2color, 50))
fill(uR2, lR2, color.new(rV2color, 95), "rVWAP #2 Bands Fill")


///------------------------------------------- START ROLLING VWAP LABELS --------------------------------------------///

//Calculate % deviation
rvwapPer1 = close > rVWAP1 ? -((close - rVWAP1) / close) * 100 : ((rVWAP1 - close) / rVWAP1) * 100

rvwapPer2 = close > rVWAP2 ? -((close - rVWAP2) / close) * 100 : ((rVWAP2 - close) / rVWAP2) * 100

//Draw RVWAP 1 lines & labels
var label rVWAP1_label = na
var line rVWAP1_line = na

if rvOn1 and drawVLabels
    // Delete previous line and label if they exist
    if not na(rVWAP1_label)
        label.delete(rVWAP1_label)
    if not na(rVWAP1_line)
        line.delete(rVWAP1_line)

    // Create new VWAP line and label
    rVWAP1_line := line.new(x1=bar_index + 5,
         y1=rVWAP1, 
         x2=bar_index + 11, 
         y2=rVWAP1, 
         color=rV1color, 
         style=line.style_dotted, 
         width=1)
        
    rVWAP1_label := label.new(x=bar_index + 15,
         y=rVWAP1,
         text=str.tostring(tfI1) + "_" + "rVWAP" + "(" + str.tostring(rvwapPer1, format.percent) +")",
         textcolor=rV1color, 
         color=color.new(color.white, 100), 
         size=size.large,
         style=label.style_label_left, 
         text_font_family=font.family_monospace)

//Draw RVWAP 2 lines & labels
var label rVWAP2_label = na
var line rVWAP2_line = na

if rvOn2 and drawVLabels
    // Delete previous line and label if they exist
    if not na(rVWAP2_label)
        label.delete(rVWAP2_label)
    if not na(rVWAP2_line)
        line.delete(rVWAP2_line)

    // Create new VWAP line and label
    rVWAP2_line := line.new(x1=bar_index + 5,
         y1=rVWAP2, 
         x2=bar_index + 11, 
         y2=rVWAP2, 
         color=rV2color, 
         style=line.style_dotted, 
         width=1)
        
    rVWAP2_label := label.new(x=bar_index + 15,
         y=rVWAP2,
         text=str.tostring(tfI2) + "_" + "rVWAP" + "(" + str.tostring(rvwapPer2, format.percent) +")",
         textcolor=rV2color, 
         color=color.new(color.white, 100), 
         size=size.large,
         style=label.style_label_left, 
         text_font_family=font.family_monospace)

I've tried many ways to delete the text if the % changes and replace it and nothing has worked.
The reason I believe this to "maybe" be a bug is that if I disable the labels in my indicator and re enable them, it works perfectly UNTIL i switch the charts timeframe, I have to do it again...Image showing text "overlapping"

Need a minimal reproducible code example that can compile and show the issue.

@vitruvius Can I email the code to you ?

Please upload it here. We don't need the whole code. Just a minimal reproducible example is enough.

@vitruvius Thank you, i just updated the original post with the MRE

I'm not able to reproduce the issue with this code. How can I do that?

I just reproduced it. I added another vwap to this script to compare
Once added to your chart, it will either start doing it right away or once you go to another timeframe like minute 5
A volatile pair is best to show changes in %
Thanks

Okay, I was able to reproduce the issue. Did you try just creating one label instance and modifying it? Instead of, deleting the old label and creating a new one. That solves the issue in my case.

@vitruvius I actually contacted pine team and they confirmed it was a bug
However your suggestion has fixed it! Thanks very much!

Good to know. I will convert my comment to an answer then.

Instead of deleting the old label and creating a new one on each bar, you can just modify the label object. This will also help you with the performance of the script.
//Draw RVWAP 1 lines & labels
var label rVWAP1_label = label.new(na, na,na, textcolor=rV1color, color=color.new(color.white, 100), size=size.large, style=label.style_label_left, text_font_family=font.family_monospace)
var line rVWAP1_line = na

if rvOn1 and drawVLabels
    // Delete previous line and label if they exist
    // Create new VWAP line and label
    rVWAP1_line := line.new(x1=bar_index + 5,
         y1=rVWAP1, 
         x2=bar_index + 11, 
         y2=rVWAP1, 
         color=rV1color, 
         style=line.style_dotted, 
         width=1)

    label.set_xy(rVWAP1_label, bar_index + 15, rVWAP1)
    label.set_text(rVWAP1_label, str.tostring(tfI1) + "_" + "rVWAP" + "(" + str.tostring(rvwapPer1, format.percent) +")")

